# OpenCV error img is incompatible with cv::Mat

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Just realized of a surprising thing when using the following code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros((720, 1280, 2), dtype=np.uint8)
b = np.zeros((720, 1280), dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.circle(b, (100,100),3,1,-1)   # works
cv2.circle(a[..., 0], (100,100),3,1,-1)  # does not work
```

Calling exactly same function with exactly same arguments is not working. Is this related with how numpy deals with arrays internally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on Github and it seems the reason is due to OpenCV `cv::Mat` and `cv::Umat` support per-row step, but not per-element step. It means that elements in a row should be compact without holes. `a[..., 0]` creates array with per-element step. This memory layout cannnot be converted to `cv::Mat` automatically and the only solution is data copy.

See https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/741

Comment: wrong repository. that one is just for building the wheel. you need to file any issues against the `/opencv/opencv` repo. -- don't expect the structure of `cv::Mat` to change anytime soon. that'd be a breaking change in some situations. it would be sensible to have this flexibility though.

Answer (score 2):

when translating between numpy arrays and OpenCV `cv::Mat`, OpenCV's bindings require the numpy array to be **contiguous**.

Numpy slicing commonly produces non-contiguous arrays because it merely adjusts strides and offsets, yet still refers to the entire original data.

The simplest way to "fix" this is to make a copy of the numpy array: `a[..., 0].copy()`

**BUT!!!** that's a copy, so changes to it won't be reflected in the original array. If you do the copy, you need to take care to copy the data back into your source array.

```py
plane = a[..., 0].copy() # copy makes contiguous
cv2.circle(plane, (100,100), 3, 1, -1)
a[..., 0] = plane
```

Comment: `b[..., 0]` would have shape `(720,)`, i.e. it's not even a picture, just a list of values. OpenCV's `circle()` should reject that entirely. it can't draw in a flat list of numbers. I'm surprised to hear you claim it "works".

Comment: Thank you because answerd my "stupid" question about `b[..., 0]`, I didn't notice that it was a one-dimensional array, so I deleted that comment and upvote your answer, but what about a 2 dimensional array like `b[:, 20:1000]` or `b[20:700, :]`? Or even 3-dimensional array like a[:, 20:1000, :]? They are still "work". Sorry for deleting the previous comment but I'm still baffled by this, can you explain it?

Comment: use `np.info()` on each of those expressions, look at the "contiguous:" line or check the `.flags['C_CONTIGUOUS']` property. `b[:,20:1000]` (non-contiguous) _might_ work anyway because `cv::Mat` does support a row stride, IIRC (but not pixel strides or channel strides).